# Can the condition $y \notin \mathrm{var} \, \varphi$ be weakened to $y \notin \mathrm{free} \, \varphi$ in the definition of $\exists !$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This definition is taken from *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition) by Wolfgang Rautenberg, p. 72. Let us define $\exists!x\varphi := \exists x\varphi \land \forall x\forall y(\varphi \land \varphi \frac{y}{x} \to x=y)$, with $y \notin \mathrm{var} \, \varphi$. An interesting question that arose while reading this was whether I could weaken $y \notin \mathrm{var} \, \varphi$. I've proven that $y \notin \mathrm{free} \, \varphi$ is a *necessary* condition for this definition of $\exists !$ to be sensible, but is it also a *sufficient* condition?

It seems so to me. If $y$ appears only as bound in $\varphi$, then all evaluations of $\varphi$ in models $\mathcal{M}^a_y$ under the first $\forall y$ in the definition of $\exists !$ are overridden by another $\exists y$ or $\forall y$ in $\varphi$ itself. This seems to preserve the intended meaning of the definition.

Thank you for your help and insights! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

Consider the case $\exists ! \varphi$ where $\varphi := \forall y \psi$. We have that $y \notin \text{free}(\varphi)$ but $y \in \text{var}(\varphi)$.

What is the result of $\varphi^y_x$? It will be (according to defintion page 59): $(\forall y \psi)^y_x = \forall y (\psi)^y_x$ and the new occurrence of $y$ has been "captured" by the quantifier.

You cannot "relax" it; what you can do is $y \notin \text{free}(\varphi)$ **and** $\varphi^y_x$ is *collision-free* (page 70).

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about collision. Quantifiers can be really tricky to "tame"! :)

Comment: @Godbless - you are welcome :-)

Comment: BTW, I wrote down $\exists ! x \forall y P(x,y)$ in its full form and I can now see why collision must absolutely be avoided, as there is a model of $\exists ! x \forall y P(x,y)$ (more precisely, of the formula which corresponds to this abbreviation) with $x_0 \neq x_1$ such that $\forall y P(x_0,y)$ and $\forall y P(x_1,y)$, which clearly violates our intuitive understanding of unique existence.